# Apply filter of document on elastic search , search api of all documents

Tags: elasticsearch

hi I want to search in all index but want to restrict few items based on filters on docs which will be different for every doc. for example I have 2 docs

1 is Tables and 2nd is column and filter will be dynamic always

for tables for example my filter look like this

```
{
   "bool":{
      "should":[
         {
            "bool":{
               "must":[
                  {
                     "term":{
                        "source_id":31302162
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "terms":{
                        "folder_name":[
                           "HEALTHCARE"
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "bool":{
               "must":[
                  {
                     "term":{
                        "source_id":31308790
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "terms":{
                        "folder_name":[
                           "TRANSPORTATION"
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "terms":{
               "source_id":[
                  31317941,
                  31318737
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "terms":{
               "parent_id":[
                  31277907,
                  31277893
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

and for column :

```
{
   "bool":{
      "should":[
         {
            "terms":{
               "parent_id":[
                  31317941,
                  31318737
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

now as I am doing search in overall all indexes using /_search api of elastic search .I want these filters to apply on just respective index. like 1st on tables and 2nd on column .